# In Microsoft Odata client, how to send empty json object in body?

Tags: .net-core, odata, microsoft-odata

I use Microsoft.OData.Client to call a function on an entity. I got an serialization erro back from the api. The api needs a empty `{}` body in the request to work properly.
Is that possible to achive using Microsoft.OData.Client? Maybe there is a configuration that I haven't found?

```
        var wo = _client.JtTaskSet.Where(x => x.TaskSeq == woNo).FirstOrDefault();
        var qry = wo.JtTask_EndWork();
        var res = qry.Execute();
```